# Populate dynamical form with json

Tags: javascript, html, json, jquery-mobile

I am trying to populate  an html form using js, and j query and i have encountered a problem.

The form is growing according to the user request, the user need to fill 4 different inputs and if he wants he can click on a button and add another 4 inputs.
here is the form:

```
<form action="#main" method="post" id="exercise-form">
 <div data-role="header" class="header" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed">
                <a class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="check" onclick="$('form#exercise-form').trigger('submit');
                        resetExerciseForm();" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
                <h1 class="text">Add a Workout</h1>
                <a href="#main" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-left" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" onclick="$('form#exercise-form').trigger('reset');
                        resetExerciseForm();"></a>
            </div>

            <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-field-contain ui-body ui-br">
                <label for="date" class="text">Workout Date:</label>
                <input type="date" name="date" value="" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset form-element serializable" style="color: white; font-family:'Ariel'; text-shadow:none;">
            </div>
            <br>

            <div id="exercise-template" style="display: none;">
                <!-- Exercise name -->
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="ex-name" class="text">Exercise Name:</label>
                    <input class="form-element serializable" type="text" name="ex-name-1" value="" style="color: white; font-family:'Ariel'; text-shadow:none;"/>
                </div>

                <div class="ui-grid-b">
                    <!-- Number of Sets -->
                    <div class="ui-block-c">
                        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <label for="set-number" class="text">Sets:</label>
                            <input class="form-element serializable" type="number" name="set-number-1" value="" style="color: white; font-family:'Ariel'; text-shadow:none;"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Number of Repetitions -->
                    <div class="ui-block-c">
                        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <label for="rpt-number" class="text">Repetitions:</label>
                            <input class="form-element serializable" type="number" name="rpt-number-1" value="" style="color: white; font-family:'Ariel'; text-shadow:none;"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Weight -->
                    <div class="ui-block-c">
                        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <label for="weight" class="text">Weight:</label>
                            <input class="form-element serializable" type="number" name="weight-1" value="" style="color: white; font-family:'Ariel'; text-shadow:none;"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
            </div>
            <label for="text-area" class="text">Json:</label>
            <span id="text-area" style="color: white; font-family:'Ariel'; text-shadow:none;"></span>
        </form>
```

When the user want to add one more exercise the next java script is running:

```
function addExerciseForm() {
    var oldId = exerciseId;
    var newId = ++exerciseId;

    document.getElementsByName('ex-name' + oldId).name = 'ex-name' + newId;
    document.getElementsByName('set-number' + oldId).name = 'set-number' + newId;
    document.getElementsByName('rpt-number' + oldId).name = 'rpt-number' + newId;
    document.getElementsByName('weight' + oldId).name = 'weight' + newId;

    var clonable = document.getElementById('exercise-template');
    var clone = clonable.cloneNode(true); //true for deep clone

    clonable.id = "exercise" + newId;
    clone.id = 'exercise-template';
    clonable.style.display = 'initial';

    // var addButton = document.getElementById('add-exercise-button');
    clonable.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
    clonable.removedNode();
    clone.parentNode.appendChild(clonable);
}
```

As u can see the hole div with the id exercise-template is being cloned with different id that is increased by 1.
When i clone the div i am trying to change the name of  so when i populate it from a json file i wont have more then one label with the same name.

The problem is that when i look at the DOM after cloning the div i can see that the name hasn't change while if i use chrome debug mode i can see that the line:

```
document.getElementsByName('ex-name' + oldId).name = 'ex-name' + newId;
```

actually giving me the wanted element. But the populate script cant find the name of the new element.

here is the populate script:

```
function populateExerciseForm() {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'json/exercise.json',
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        success: function (response, status) {
            console.log(response, status);
            if (status === "success") {
                // we expect a response in a JSON format
                // response = JSON.parse(response);
                $('#exercise-form').populate(response);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Anyone know what is the problem?
or for example how can i take the next json and let the first 4 values inside the first 4 inputs and so on..?

json example:

```
{
    "ex-name-1": "abc",
        "set-number-1": 2,
        "rpt-number-1": 3,
        "weight-1": 20,
        "ex-name-1": "efg",
        "set-number-1": 4,
        "rpt-number-1": 4,
        "weight-1": 123
}
```

I hope my problem is clear.
Thanks ahead!!